# High CPU usage for a brand new Flutter app for Windows

Tags: windows, flutter

I just started a brand new Flutter project for Windows following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymGFtpl7SBA), and I'm experiencing pretty high CPU usage, even though the app is doing absolutely nothing.

I've tried on both `stable` and `beta` channels, both `debug` and `release` modes, and I still experience that problem.

Did I miss anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I solved my problem by updating Flutter and creating a brand new project. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using default font provided by flutter make the ui trying to adapt UI every time. If you define your own font like roboto in pubspec.yaml, the UI will stop adapting font and widget will stop rebuild every time.